# Modify response structure using Eloquent: API Resources

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-eloquent-resource

I am newbie in Laravel. I am using laravel as a REST End Point, I use Eloquent: API Resources for transforming my data to JSON.

I am using Collection and Resource to parse my data came from my query. So below is the structure of my response:

```
data:
    0
        id
        name
    1
        id
        name
```

Now I need to have some categorization in the data, hence I require the data structure to be in below format

```
data:
    24H
        0
            id
            name
        1
            id
            name
    7D
        0
            id
            name
        1
            id
            name
```

I tried couple of ways to accomplish this, the static way I tried for testing was to change the **ResourceCollection**'s toArray method and append the key 24H for the data we get.

But I know that is not correct and generic way.

I would like to know how I can achieve the above response format in generic and extensible manner.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the 24H and 7D keys coming from some property of the models?

Comment: I have executed my own select query to get the data.
I can add another column as type that is 24H or 7D in the SQL itself, if that can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Collections have a groupBy method that may help you here, make sure the column you want to use as the key is selected as well. So if you have

```
data: 
    0: 
        id: 1
        name: Bob
        category: 24H

    1: 
        id: 2
        name: Bill
        category: 7D
```

Then `$data->groupBy('category')` would return the following

```
data: 
    24H:
        0: 
            id: 1
            name: Bob
            category: 24H

    7D: 
        0:
            id: 2
            name: Bill
            category: 7D
```

Comment: Thanks, however I have a huge query so I use DB::select and provided my RAW query in it.
I tried using groupBy in it, but it gave error ```Call to a member function groupBy() on array```
This is my syntax: ```DB::select($sql, [$this->user['id']])->groupBy('type');```

Comment: Take the array you get back from the DB::select and put it in a collection first collect(DB::select($sql, [$this->user['id']))->groupBy('type')

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked after some modification on resource class where I transform data into array.